# can't connect to *.onion sites with python (<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>)

Tags: python, proxy, tor, socks

I'm trying to access *.onion sites using python. Didn't success yet, though.
I've read a lot of stackoverflow questions&answers, tried a lot of different ways of resolving this problem: I tried using `Python 2.7` and `Python 3.5`, tried using `urllib`, `urllib2`, `requests` (then I found out requests doesn't work with socks), `pysocks`, etc, but nothing seems to work.
Right now I'm at the point where I only get the following Error:

```
> <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

No, I don't have a firewall, and yes, I have a good internet connection, and yes, the site does exist.
I think the problem is that it's an *.onion link.

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
import socks
import socket
import urllib
import urllib.request

socks.set_default_proxy(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
socket.socket = socks.socksocket
r = urllib.request.urlopen("http://xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion")
r.read()
```

and this is what I'm getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1239             try:
-> 1240                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
   1241             except OSError as err: # timeout error

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers)
   1082         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1083         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
   1084 

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers)
   1127             body = body.encode('iso-8859-1')
-> 1128         self.endheaders(body)
   1129 

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body)
   1078             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1079         self._send_output(message_body)
   1080 

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body)
    910 
--> 911         self.send(msg)
    912         if message_body is not None:

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    853             if self.auto_open:
--> 854                 self.connect()
    855             else:

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in connect(self)
    825         self.sock = self._create_connection(
--> 826             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    827         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    692     err = None
--> 693     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    694         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    731     addrlist = []
--> 732     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    733         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-1e30353c3485> in <module>()
----> 1 r = urllib.request.urlopen("http://xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion:80")
      2 r.read()

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    160     else:
    161         opener = _opener
--> 162     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    163 
    164 def install_opener(opener):

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    463             req = meth(req)
    464 
--> 465         response = self._open(req, data)
    466 
    467         # post-process response

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    481         protocol = req.type
    482         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 483                                   '_open', req)
    484         if result:
    485             return result

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    441         for handler in handlers:
    442             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 443             result = func(*args)
    444             if result is not None:
    445                 return result

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_open(self, req)
   1266 
   1267     def http_open(self, req):
-> 1268         return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
   1269 
   1270     http_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

C:\Users\yella\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1240                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers)
   1241             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1242                 raise URLError(err)
   1243             r = h.getresponse()
   1244         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

I'm very new to all this stuff, so I might be missing some really simple parts. But I'll be grateful for any help.

ps: when trying to access not an *.onion site, I get the following:

```
[WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Recent versions of Requests [support SOCKS proxies](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#socks) just fine.

Comment: Tor itself is not an http proxy, so if you just connect to it as an ordinary socks5 proxy it won't resolve .onion domains. You shoud take a look at http://sacharya.com/crawling-anonymously-with-tor-in-python/

Comment: Have you tried using torsocks? It's the easiest way IMO.

Comment: @larsks I just tried using requests, and got the same error: requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: SOCKSHTTPConnectionPool(host='xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.contrib.socks.SOCKSConnection object at 0x0000000003320BE0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))

Comment: Do you have a Tor daemon running on your Windows machine and listening on port 9050?  From the looks of it, Tor isn't running on your computer or it's using a different port.

Comment: @drew010 Tor is running, though the task itself requires connection to onion w/o tor running or even being installed on the computer. is it even possible?

Comment: The only way you can connect to .onion sites is via the Tor network through it's SOCKS proxy.  I'm not aware of any other way besides using a `tor2web` type website which I'd highly discourage.  So pretty much the answer is if you want to do this in code, Tor needs to be running on the local machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on Linux but the code you supplied didn't work for me.  From the looks of it the DNS resolution is not happening over Tor (based on error 11001 `WSAHOST_NOT_FOUND`).  I'm a little suspicious that it's actually using Tor because of the 10061 (connection refused) error too.

In any case, I was able to get it working with this:

```
import urllib2
import socks
from sockshandler import SocksiPyHandler

opener = urllib2.build_opener(SocksiPyHandler(socks.SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050, True))
print opener.open("http://xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion").read()
```

PySocks says in their [docs](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySocks):

> Note that monkeypatching may not work for all standard modules or for
>   all third party modules, and generally isn't recommended.
>   Monkeypatching is usually an anti-pattern in Python.

The monkey patching is the use of `socket.socket = socks.socksocket`.

If possible, use [Requests](http://python-requests.org/) with the `socks5h://` protocol handlers for your proxies:

```
import requests
import json

proxies = {
    'http': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050',
    'https': 'socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050'
}

data = requests.get("http://xmh57jrzrnw6insl.onion",proxies=proxies).text

print(data)
```